# Excel: Extracting numbers from a string with variable length

Tags: excel, excel-formula, variable-length

I have a column with data that looks like this:

| Day |
| --- |
| D003 |
| D004 |
| D008 |
| D010 |
| D012 |
| D028 |

And in the next column, I need to extract just the 3, 4, 10, 12, etc. with NO leading 0's. I tried the following:

```
=IF(D8="D003 Predose","30",IF(D8="D003 End","31",IF(D8="D003 4hours","34",RIGHT(D8,LEN(D8)-FIND(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(D8,"0",""),1),D8)+1))))
```

Which works for the 4, 5, 8. But for the 12, 17, 21, etc it only gives me the last number. How do I account for the variable length of those strings? I'm really new at Excel and creating formulas "from scratch" so I apologize if the answer is right in front of my nose. If there's a cleaner way to do this, I'm also all ears.

Comment: Will there only ever be one letter in the string ("D")?

Comment: Yes, it will only ever be D###

Comment: `=--MID(A1,2,3)` should work.

Comment: =--MID(A1,2,3) works, I had NO idea you could just add the -- to the front. I see the result works, but just so I understand, exactly what is it doing? How does it "know" to remove the leading 0's from the different lengths of the digits? I.e., 003 = 3 and 012 = 12

Comment: Rouch explanation: essentially, the `--` ends up convert the string to a number. Unless your cells are formatted to include leading zeroes, you won't see them.

Comment: Extremely helpful. Thanks all.